# blazor wasm forward authentication to external API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, blazor-webassembly

I have a blazor wasm app using AAD authentication, created using : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-azure-active-directory?view=aspnetcore-6.0
This part works really well.

I have another asp.net core app (not hosting the wasm app) that I need to forward the authentication to when doing API calls. I want to "know" which user is doing the call (and check that it is true, obviously). I keep getting 401 errors to my API calls.
I have added the following code to the client app, hoping this would forward the current user to the http call:

```
services
   .AddHttpClient("LoginAPI", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7215")) // not the same as the URL hosting the current WASM app
   .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("LoginAPI"));
```

In the server app, I added the "UseAuthentication" and "UseAuthorization" as usual, and this:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
```

My server appsettings:

```
"AzureAd": {
  "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common",
  "TenantId": "common",
  "ClientId": "***"
}
```

And my client appsettings:

```
"AzureAd": {
  "Authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common",
  "ClientId": "***", // same as in the server
  "ValidateAuthority": true
}
```

Any idea how to make my blazor WASM app authenticate with the other asp.net core API?

Thanks!

Comment: Using this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67147315/1758142
I managed to see the bearer token in the header being sent to the server. but now the server is giving me this error :
`IDX12720: Token string does not match the token formats: JWE (header.encryptedKey.iv.ciphertext.tag) or JWS (header.payload.signature)`

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else arrives here. I managed to make it work following this :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67147315/1758142.

it led met to another error where the token sent was not valid, I found out that for "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common", I can't use the scope "https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read". I replace it with both of these:
https://graph.microsoft.com/offline_access
https://graph.microsoft.com/profile